# (Stripe API) Able to obtain bank_account token, but not card token

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am able to create a client-side token for a `bank_account`, but am unable to do so in the same manner for a `card` (Stripe Connected Account); the documentation suggests that these processes are nearly identical.

- [Create `bank_account` Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/external_account_bank_accounts/create)
- [Create `card` Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/external_account_cards/create)

**Working with `bank_account`:**

With the following client-side (JS), I can create a token; the token is returned.

```
result = stripe.createToken('bank_account', {
        account_holder_name: 'Test Account Holder',     
        account_holder_type: 'individual',
        account_number:'000123456789', // Stripe test account number
        routing_number: '110000000', // Stripe test routing number
        currency: 'usd',
        country:'US'
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log("OK");
    console.log(result);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("ERROR:");
    console.log(error);
});
```

**Not working with `card`:**

However, when I replace the `bank_account` parameter with a `card` parameter and the following required parameters, I receive the following error:

```
result = stripe.createToken('card', {
        number: '5200828282828210', // Stripe testing card
        exp_month: '12',
        exp_year:'2020',
        cvc: '1234',
        currency: 'usd',
        name:'Test Account Holder Name',
        default_for_currency: true      
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log("OK");
    console.log(result);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("ERROR:");
    console.log(error);
});
```

`Error: Invalid value for token type: value should be one of the following strings: account, bank_account, pii, apple_pay. You specified: card.`

**My confusion:**

The error suggests that I use some other parameters, and `card` is not one of those parameters.

I know that `pii` is basically for SSNs (US), I've just used `bank_account` successfully, and the `card` version (according to their docs) seem to be identical. I've tried `account` just for the hack of it (to no avail), and `apple_pay` is obviously not applicable.

Why am I receiving this error? How can I resolve this and receive a `card` token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you can not pass raw card details to the method client-side. This is blocked by default as it impacts your PCI compliance status. This is documented here: https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance

Instead, you need to use [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#elements). This library offers UI components that you can use to collect the card details securely client-side. You can see some examples in action here: https://stripe.github.io/elements-examples/

Answer (score 0):

`card` is supposed to be the key for the card object you provide - you have a comma where there should be a colon.

```
result = stripe.createToken('card': {
    number: '5200828282828210', // Stripe testing card
    exp_month: '12',
    exp_year:'2020',
    cvc: '1234',
    currency: 'usd',
    name:'Test Account Holder Name',
    default_for_currency: true      
}).then(function(result) {
  console.log("OK");
  console.log(result);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log("ERROR:");
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure if you fixed my question, but if there was a colon there, that was an unfortunate typo in the question alone (my actual API request did not have a colon).

Comment: createToken takes 1 key-value arg, you are passing it 2: the string 'card' and a card object. You should be passing it 1 arg, the key 'card' and a card object. This is outlined in the documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card) which is clearly using a different version of the API - tokens.create vs. createToken. Your comma is supposed to be a colon after 'card'.